# Max connection user in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to increase Max-connection upto 1000 .How much RAM is required current 4GB RAM with Max-connection 500 ...

If any formula please share to me

Comment: http://www.mysqlcalculator.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting read for [How MySQL uses memory](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/memory-use.html)

We have,
Global Buffers: key_buffer_size, innodb_buffer_pool_size, innodb_additional_mem_pool_size, innodb_log_buffer_size, query_cache_size

and

Per Thread Buffers: read_buffer_size, read_rnd_buffer_size, sort_buffer_size, join_buffer_size, thread_stack, max_allowed_packet, net_buffer_length

To calculate present status you can [download procedure here](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/mysql-memory-utilization.sql) and just run it from MySQL.

I guess we can formulate number of Threads `(nT) = ( R - GB  ) / PTB`

> Where,
>
> R - Ram
>
> GB - Global Buffers
>
> PTB - Per Thread Buffers